# How do you show that a function is differentiable if there isn't a specific $x_{0}$ given?

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives

Let's say we got a function given, simple example like $f(x)=x^{2}$. We are supposed to show this function is differentiable but there is no specific $x_{0}$ given where we check this.

What shall I do in this case?

Because I always used this formula to show it's differentiable:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}$$

and check if for left and right side there is same solution, if so, it's differentiable.

But I cannot use this formula because there is no $x_{0}$.

What then? Can I just derivate the function and if it works, conclude it is differentiable? Oh and additionally show that there is no definition-gap, jump,..?

Please do tell me what to do in such a case, I wouldn't know what to do. I smell a task like that in my exam.

Comment: In questions like this one it is usually assumed you have to prove differentiability for *any point* $\;x_0\;$ in the domain of definition of the function, and in this case: in the whole real line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calculate the limit for **any** $\;x_0\;$ :

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{x^2-x_0^2}{x-x_0}=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{(x-x_0)(x+x_0)}{x-x_0}=\lim_{x\to x_0}(x+x_0)=2x_0$$

Comment: @cnmesr What "the number" are you talking about? I don't understand you...

Comment: Ohh really so easy, thanks! :) Never mind my comment, I understood it.

Comment: Btw, it wouldn't have been enough if I showed that a function hasn't got any gaps, jumps and stuff like that to proof differentiability, right?

Comment: @cnmesr Indeed: it isn't enough. Try with the function absolute value, $\;f(x)=|x|\;$ at $\;x_0=0\;$ . It hasn't jumps, gaps there but it isn't differentiable there.

Comment: Ok last question, sry now questions come to my mind... If I solve a task like that like in your answer, it is enough if I only do it once right? So I don't need to show it for left and right side?

Comment: @cnmesr Of course. What's been shown above is that **The Limit** exists finitely and thus the function's differentiable at **any** point $\;x_0\;$ in its domain. If we had some problems calculating the limit then we can, as usual, do the left limit, right limit and verify they both exist finitely and are equal.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just take the derivative because you're assuming what you're trying to prove. That being said, here's what we do:

As mentioned in my comment, we'll use the $x-c$ definition (you actually wrote it incorrectly in your question).

We say that $f$ is differentiable at $c$ if the limit

$$ \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c} $$

exists. We call such a limit the derivative. Some books give this with $c$ relabeled as $x_0$ as you have done above.

So let $f(x) = x^2$. Then what? Well,

$$ \frac{x^2 - c^2}{x-c} = x+c $$

and now you can take the limit as $x \to c$. Done!

Comment: We didn't have this in our readings but I understand what you did now. Btw, what exactly did I write incorrectly in my question? Edit: Oh I see I have accidently written $\infty$ :o

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \left(\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right)$$

Comment: Oh no, not this one.. I really don't like it :D There is no other way? ^.^

Comment: You can use the $x-c$ definition. I'll post an answer.